# Safe to set permissions to 757 temporarily to update via wp-cli?

Tags: permissions, cron, wp-cli

LEMP stack on digitalocean VPS.

I haven't been able to get "wp core update" to work unless public (or "Other") has execute permission, i.e. 757 or 777.

Otherwise, it throws "Error: Could not create directory" every time.

I checked that the user who owns the wordpress install is the same user running "wp core update"

Things I've attempted so far are setting permissions to 775, chown www-data:www-data, moving the wp-cli file.

I have multiple websites running on this droplet/server, and each experience the same problem.

So, let's say I set a cronjob to set permissions to 757, update, and set back to 755 directories 644 files 660 wp-config.php

Is that relatively safe to do? Would I be putting my clients' sites in considerably jeopardy doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I think setting a cron job to automatically turn permissions on and off might be a bit of an extreme workround :-) I think it is probably worth spending the time to set up working permissions on your server, rather than a cron job which could introduce other problems.

This has been a good resource for me -  https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress.

This has also been a great resource for me -
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-16-04

These are the steps I have used to allow automatic / wp-cli updates of WordPress and plugins on an Ubuntu droplet with NGINX as the web server.

1. Set the recommended file and folder permissions:

   ```
   750 for Directories
   640 for Files
   except for wp-config.php, this should be 440.
   ```

   To do this for directories:

   ```
   find /srv/www/your-site/ -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
   ```

   and files:

   ```
   find /srv/www/your-site/ -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
   ```

   and wp-config.php:

   ```
   sudo chmod 440 your-site/wp-config.php
   ```
2. Set the owner and group to **web:www-data** where **web** is a non-root user with sudo user permissions.

   ```
   sudo chown -R web:www-data /srv/www/your-site
   ```

   This command will give you more information of what user / group NGINX is running under:

   ```
   ps -eo pid,comm,euser,supgrp | grep nginx
   ```

   https://superuser.com/questions/398833/how-to-determine-the-user-and-group-of-a-deamon-in-ubuntu

   The group is www-data in my case.
3. Set setgid bit so that all new files inherit the group of the parent directory.

   ```
   sudo find /srv/www/your-site -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
   ```
4. Give the group write access to the wp-content directory.

   ```
    sudo chmod g+w /srv/www/your-site/wp-content
   ```
5. Give the group write access to the plugins, themes and uploads directories.

   ```
   sudo chmod -R g+w /srv/www/your-site/wp-content/themes
   sudo chmod -R g+w /srv/www/your-site/wp-content/plugins
   sudo chmod -R g+w /srv/www/your-site/wp-content/uploads
   ```
6. Make sure you are running the core update command as the owner in step 2 if necessary switching to that user first.

   ```
   su web
   wp core update
   ```

Comment: I run this setup with the www-data user's write access restricted to uploads, and I commit to command line updates.